# jQuery ajax call crashes Chrome, Firefox but Safari is fine

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, gdata

```
var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/18508B7EDC293770?v=2&alt=json';

$.ajax({
url: url,
cache: false,
data: "",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
timeout: 5000,
success: function (d) {}
});
```

The code does not give you much, but I think the problem is url specific. I've been trying to retrieve a GData JSON feed, but notice that Firefox and Chrome keep the script hanging, forcing me to manually shutdown the browser. The feed seems to be valid.

I have no means of debugging as no errors are given. Any suggestions as how to approach the debugging process in this case?

Comment: Is this cross-site?  Do you need to be using JSON-P instead of JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a long-existing conflict between GData and jQuery.
The solution was to add the following parameters to the url:

```
alt=json-in-script&callback=?
```